# Is it possible to implement pagination in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am fetching JSON Data from mysql database which contains latitude & longitude. I add markers in map by looping through json. Is it possible to add markers as needed when map is scrolled?

Comment: Yes, in fact I have done this with my app.  Note that your question does not really depend on Google Maps, it's just a general pagination question.

Comment: and what you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: If there are many records in Database it will take time to load. In recyclerview we can keep loading next set of records as we scroll. I would like to know any similar concept available for Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

You can just store your `Marker`'s

```
private Set<Marker, LatLng> set;
```

then add some callback to your `GoogleMap`

```
this.map.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMove() {
        addMarkersIfNecessary();
    }
});
this.map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        addMarkersIfNecessary();
    }
});


private void addMarkersIfNecessary() {
    final LatLng center = this.map.getCameraPosition().target
    // check if markers are within N meters from the center
    // add them to the map
}
```